18th century coordinates Tenerife meridan
I am studying a French 18th century boat itinerary. Sailors use a Dutch map based on the meridian of Tenerife that lies at 16° 38′ 22″ W of the current international prime meridian Greenwich (Wikipedia).
The first coordinate recorded in the logbook is the French port of Lorient : 46°6N; 13°5 E (converted into 46,1 dd; 13,08 dd)
How can I map these coordinates into QGIS?

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37274 you can try the custom projection approach that is mentioned.
